# Why is the serial communication with this device failing?

Tags: embedded, ttyusb, minicom, uart

I have two serial to USB adapters connected to my computer, each one is connected to a microcontroller.

What I want to do is send commands to each microcontroller through UART (I'm using minicom), but only one is succeeding. Both send data to the computer, but only one is capable of receiving it.

This is the result after sending a command to one device.

[image]

This is what happens with the other device.

[image]

It's not that the connection is wrong, because I switched to Windows and both of them worked. Also, I have to add that the adapter started to fail when I attempted to transmit information to both devices at the same time (as *ttyUSB0* and *ttyUSB1*). It was working fine before that attempt. After that, it doesn't matter if only one is connected, one always works and the other doesn't. It is recognized by the computer as *ttyUSB0* but it never receives the information.

As more evidence that it's the software that is wrong and not the hardware: the LED of the failing adapter never turns on when it's supposed to be receiving data.

Edit: information about the two adapters and the microcontrollers.

**Device CH341**

[11208.020500] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd

[11208.222337] usb 3-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64

[11208.222345] usb 3-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0

[11208.222348] usb 3-2.3: Product: USB Serial

[11208.232359] usb 3-2.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0

**Device FT232** (the one that doesn't receive data)

[11208.400547] usb 3-2.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd

[11208.613046] usb 3-2.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00

[11208.613056] usb 3-2.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[11208.613060] usb 3-2.1.4: Product: FT232R USB UART

[11208.613062] usb 3-2.1.4: Manufacturer: FTDI

[11208.613065] usb 3-2.1.4: SerialNumber: A9EYI2C0

[11208.621661] usb 3-2.1.4: Detected FT232RL

[11208.623137] usb 3-2.1.4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1

The microcontrollers are both Black Pill boards (STM32F401)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please specify the hardware you are using, both the serial-to-USB adapters and the attached microcontrollers.

Comment: just to verify: you're actually using the tty you want to use? Because in both your screenshots, you're using `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but you say you want to speak to the *other* adapter, so that's a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm connecting only one adapter at the same time, that's why it is always labeled as `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Every time I unplug one and plug the other, the label is `/dev/ttyUSB0`.